# Meteor helper as temp storage

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to use a helper as a reactive data source to store something until I insert it into the database. I'm trying to do this:

```
Template.test.helpers({
  tempStorage: []
})

Template.test.events({
  'click .something': function() {
    tempStorage.push('value');
  }
})
```

And then in my jade I want to be able to do:

```
+each tempStorage
    +someTemplateTheUsesTheData
```

However I can't seem to push to tempStorage from my events JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

First off, [helpers should be functions](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers) (although apparently values can be assigned, thanks @saimeunt), and you cannot use them as storage.

What you can do is install the [reactive variables](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg) package and attach your tempStorage to your template, like so:

```
Template.test.onCreated(function () {
  this.tempStorage = new ReactiveVar();
  this.tempStorage.set([]);
});

Template.test.events({
  'click .something': function(event, template) {
    var tempStorage = template.tempStorage.get();
    tempStorage.push('value');
    template.tempStorage.set(tempStorage);
  }
});

Template.test.helpers({
  tempStorage: function () {
    return Template.instance().tempStorage.get();
  }
});
```

If you want to, you can use `Session` instead of a reactive variable, but your tempStorage will persist accross templates (not so temporary anymore!):

```
Template.test.onRendered(function () {
  Session.set('tempStorage', []);
});

Template.test.events({
  'click .something': function() {
    var tempStorage = Session.get('tempStorage');
    tempStorage.push('value');
    Session.set('tempStorage', tempStorage);
  }
});

Template.test.helpers({
  tempStorage: function () {
    return Session.get('tempStorage');
  }
});
```

Comment: Although a common practice inherent to reactive programming, template helpers don't necessarily have to be functions.

Comment: Yeah I sort of remembered using them without a function in my early days... but thought I would stick with the documentation. I stand corrected.

Comment: Can't quite get it to run yet, I'm assuming the template should be with a captital T, but I'm getting get not a function of undefined.

Comment: Sorry, try using `onCreated` instead of `onRendered`? And if you're talking about the `template` in the event handler, it should be with a small "t", since we're refering to the argument of the event handler (not the global `Template` class)